# How to avoid clones when using postgres_types::Json?

Tags: rust, clone

I'm currently doing a rust app which uses tokio postgres and i need to make a sql request to fetch some data based on a jsonb row. The problem is that tokio postgres use a particular type (`postgres_types::Json`) which can be used like this : `&Json::<Struct>(struct_var)`.
The struct var can't be a reference so the Json takes ownership which raises a problem as i need to use one of the struct's field after.
I could solve the problem using clone but i wanted to know before if there was an other solution which would not lower the performances.
Here is the function :

```rust
pub async fn user_exists_ipv4(
    pool: &Pool,
    ip: IpAddr,
    device: &Device,
) -> Result<Option<Uuid>, String> {
    // Get a connection from the pool
    let conn = get_connection(pool).await?;
    let country = &device.country[..];
    // Get the user id from the database
    let result = conn
        .query(
            FETCH_USER_QUERY_FOR_V4,
            &[
                &ip.to_string(),
                &Json::<Device>(device.clone()),
                &country.to_string(),
            ],
        )
        .await?
    ...
```

Comment: Are you sure `&Json(device)` doesn't work? Looks like it should, though I'm just skimming through the docs.

Comment: @kmdreko Yes it works but i actually need to clone the Device struct because it's a reference, which i would want to avoid.

Comment: I understand, and I meant without any clones. `Json` should work just fine holding a `&Device` since it's `ToSql` implementation only requires `Serialize`, which is implemented for `&T` so long as `T: Serialize`.

Comment: @kmdreko Ok, thanks to you i tried other things and doing ```&Json::<&Device>(device)``` instead of `&Json::<Device>(device)` is working fine

Comment: Is there a reason you're explicitly annotating `Json`? It seems unnecessary and a source of confusion for you

Comment: @kmdreko No, no reason, saw it with an annotation when i first saw it in a code example so I didn't really changed it. But not using this annotation would have saved me a lot of time, you're right. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use references with [`Json`](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.7.7/tokio_postgres/types/struct.Json.html), it is simply a wrapper that [implements](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.7.7/tokio_postgres/types/struct.Json.html#impl-ToSql-for-Json%3CT%3E) `ToSql` for types that are `Serialize`-able. That will include `&T` where `T: Serialize`. So you can use it with `device` directly as it is:

```
&Json::<&Device>(device)
```

You also don't need to annotate the type of `Json` explicitly since it can be inferred directly from what you pass to it. The code above could be more succinctly written as:

```
&Json(device)
```